# Liskov substitution principe and promise objects

Tags: python, solid-principles

I have a base class Report:

```
class Report(object):
    def build():
        # ... sync report build
        return build_path  # str
```

And a child class that build reports in celery:

```
class AsyncReport(Report):
    def build():
        return task.delay(...)  # celery.result.EagerResult
```

Is it violates a Liskov substitution principle? I assume that yes, it violates LSP.

**How to design such classes, when one logical operation (`build()`) has different implementations and *possible* different return types?**

For example:

- Make base abstract class Report and 2 concrete child classes: SyncReport and AsyncReport (but I'm not sure that its doesn't violates LSP)

  ```
  class Report(object):
      def build():
          # Raises NotImplementedError or has @abstractmethod decora
          pass

  class SyncReport(Report):
      def build():
          # ...
          return build_path  # str

  class AsyncReport(Report):
      def build():
          return task.delay(...)  # celery.result.EagerResult
  ```
- Don't override a build() method in AsyncReport class (it reduces a profit from inheritance)

  ```
  class Report(object):
      def build():
          # ...
          return build_path #  str

  class AsyncReport(Report):
      def build_async():
          return task.delay(...)
  ```

Comment: Doesn't `task.delay` return `AsyncResult` rather than `EagerResult`?

Comment: Is this question purely academic? Otherwise i would just use duck-typing because it is a very strong feature in Python. Just check if the method returns the right type for your needs and you are good...

Answer (score 1):

In Python inheritance technically does not play as big role as e.g. in Java due to duck-typing. However, from the design point of view you can think of some interface that both report types are expected to implement. While the concrete return type of `build()` may be different for the implementations, they still may (and should) be sharing some common contract they fulfill, so that the caller may use it uniformly without wondering about the types. For example:

```
class SyncReport(object):
    def build():
        return EagerResult(...)  # Contains build_path

class AsyncReport(object):
    def build():
        return task.delay()  # AsyncResult
```

`EagerResult` and `AsyncResult` are sub-classes of `ResultBase`, but what actually matters in Python, is that they fulfill the same contract and may be used interchangeably without knowing the exact result type. That makes `SyncReport` and `AsyncReport` interchangeable and they follow the intention of LSP (allow programming against the interface) even without a common base class.